# Reading a file inside a class within an __init__ function does not work

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file line-by-line in python using `open()`. Below is a small snippet(Snippet - 1) that works, but when put the same working logic inside a class and inside a `__init__()` function, the same function stops working and generates no output but also no error message, just finishes the execution with exit code 0.

Can you please help in identifying the issue with Snippet-2? I am assuming that `open()` does not like to be called from `__init__()`. Thanks in advance.

#Snippet - 1

```
f = open("file.txt", 'r')
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

#Snippet - 2

```
class InitProcess:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        filepath = "file.txt"
        try:
            self.fd = open(filepath)
            for line in self.fd:
                print(line)
        finally:
            self.fd.close()
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. Are you calling the class? `InitProcess()`

Comment: Can you show us how you use InitProcess class? you don't show it on your snippets

Comment: I suspect you need to do: `p = InitProcess()` at the end of your snippet 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside `__init__()` gets executed when you create a class instance (i.e., an object of the class). Try creating an object of the class like:

```
test_process = InitProcess()
```

Your code will get executed as soon as this line gets executed.